# How do I prove that this ideal is not a prime ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I have the following problem:

> Let $K$ be a field and $R=K[X,Y]/(XY)$. For $P\in K[X,Y]$ we denote $[P]$ its class in $R$. Show that the Ideal $(XY)$ is not a prime ideal.

My Idea was the following:

Let us assume $(XY)$ is a prime ideal, this means that $$PQ\in (XY)\Rightarrow Q\in (XY)~~~or~~~P\in (XY)$$ Now take $PQ=XY$, then $X\in (XY)$ but this means that $X=P(X,Y)\cdot XY$ where $P(X,Y)\in K[X,Y]$. Now in the solution they took $Y=0$ then clearly $X=0$. But then they said that this is a contradiction. But I don't see why $X=0$ is a contradiction.

Thanks for your help

Comment: It's a contradiction because $X$ is not $0$. But anyway, this proof is not quite what I'd call elegant. We can simply note that neither $X$, nor $Y$ is in $(XY)$, because all polynomials in $(XY)$ except the $0$ polynomial have degree at least two because they're multiples of $XY$, while $X, Y$ have degree one. So $XY$ is in the ideal, but its factors aren't, making it not prime.
Alternatively, $[X]$ and $[Y]$ are zero divisors in $R$, but quotients modulo a prime ideal have no zero divisors.

Comment: sorry but where do we have that $X$ is not zero, could you explain this?

Comment: Sorry could you explain your argumentation with the degree, it seems nice but I don't get it. First of all why don't we need to consider the $0$ polynomial? and then why does every polynomial in $(XY)$ have at least degree $2$ so we denoted for $P=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i X^i$ that $deg(P)=n$ for the smallest $n$ such that $a_n\neq 0$. But then couldn't we take in our case $n=1$ so $PXY$ for $P\neq 0$ then the degree would be also 1 wouldn't it?

Comment: $X$ and $0$ are both elements of $K[X,Y]$. And they're different elements. So they're not equal.
For the degree: the degree of a multivariable polynomial is given by the largest product of any of the variables. $XY$ is the product of 2 variables, so its degree is two. And any of its multiples will have degree at least two. Except the $0$ polynomial, but $X$ is not the $0$ polynomial, so that doesn't matter.

Comment: ah and so the degree of $(XYZ)$ would be at least 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible proof:

Let $\varphi : K[X,Y] \to K$ be the unique $K$-algebra homomorphism such that $\varphi(X) = 1$ and $\varphi(Y) = 0$. Then $\varphi(XY) = \varphi(X)\varphi(Y) = 1 \cdot 0 = 0$, so this factors through the quotient $K[X,Y] \to K[X,Y]/(XY) = R$ to give a homomorphism $\widetilde{\varphi} : R \to K$ such that $\widetilde{\varphi}([P]) = \varphi(P)$ for all $P \in K[X,Y]$.

Since $K$ is a field, $\widetilde{\varphi}([X]) = \varphi(X) = 1 \neq 0$, so $[X] \neq 0$. In other words, $X \notin (XY)$. Symmetrically, we must have $Y \notin (XY)$. But $XY \in (XY)$, showing that $(XY)$ is not prime.

Comment: sorry we have never talked about $K$ algebra

Comment: No problem! I just mean that $\varphi$ is the function $K[X,Y] \to K$ defined by evaluating a polynomial $P \in K[X,Y]$ at $X = 1, Y = 0$. You can check directly that this is a ring homomorphism.